# How to view merge review comments and file changes in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ee

I'm performing a merge review (code review) in GitLab. I entered some file comments then the author responded to the comments and made some changes to the files. I can view the comment thread, and the relevant portion of the original file on the merge request Overview page. And a link there will take me to a diff between the original and changed files.

But how can I see the comment, response and file diff at the same time? Open the diff link in a new window?

GitLab version = Enterprise Edition 12.10.1-ee

(Newbie stackexchange user - Apologies for any breaches of etiquette.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if [GitLab 14.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/12/22/gitlab-14-6-released/#view-inline-the-change-that-outdated-a-merge-request-thread) (December 2021) improves your use case:

> ### View inline the change that outdated a merge request thread
>
> When addressing review feedback in merge requests, you often change lines your reviewers have commented on.
> In those comment threads, GitLab indicates that new changes were made.
>
> However, to understand if those new changes address the feedback, reviewers would have to navigate away from the context of the discussion.
>
> **Now, when viewing threads related to old changes, you can view the new changes directly in the thread**.
> This improved context helps you review faster and more accurately.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_6/create-code-review-outdated-change-inline.png -- View inline the change that outdated a merge request thread]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/discussions/) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/24468).

---

[GitLab 16.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/07/22/gitlab-16-2-released/#interactive-diff-suggestions-in-merge-requests) (July 2023) adds:

> ### Interactive diff suggestions in merge requests
>
> When you suggest changes in a merge request, you can now edit your suggestions more quickly. In a comment, switch to the rich text editor and use the UI to move up and down the lines of text. With this change, you can view your suggestions exactly as they will appear when the comment is posted.
>
> The rich text editor is a new way of editing in GitLab. It’s available in merge requests, but also available alongside the plain text editor in issues and epics.
>
> We plan to have the rich text editor available in more areas of GitLab soon and we are actively working on that. You can follow our progress [here](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/10378).
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_2/knowledge-suggest-changes.png -- Interactive diff suggestions in merge requests]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/reviews/suggestions.html#using-the-rich-text-editor) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/406726).

Comment: Wow! From the issue I understand that this feature disappeared accidentally, I am pretty sure it was there some 6 - 7 years ago when I used gitlab!

Comment: But, based on your answer I understand that 14.6 fixes the issue?

Comment: @Kostas Yes, sorry, I mixed up my comments. (I have deleted my previous one)

Comment: I asked our admin to update our gitlab, but the code changes still do not appear. Is there a setting I can use to enable this?

Comment: @Kostas There should not be any particular setting to add on the client side: the web page should reflect the new feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all the merge requests, you can check that in the left panel as 'Merge request' option. If you check the particular merge request, you can see `Discussion, Commits , Changes` at the bottom. It will be easier here for you to check what changes has been made.

Comment: Does your suggestion still apply after the merge has been performed? Since I posted the question, the merge request has been performed and I don't see what you describe. After clicking on the merge request I see what amounts to tabs for Overview, Commits, and Changes, directly under the merge request name.These tabs will show me the discussions and file diffs, but not at the same time. On the Overview tab I can see all the discussions but no file diffs. And on the Changes tab I can see all the file diffs but none of the discussions.